# opengl single colour and multiple colour performance issue

Tags: opengl

I am drawing a huge model with 6 million elements(quads and tris) using glBindBuffer. If I give single colour for all components(component, is a group of elements) the model rotating is faster compared to components with different colours. May I know the reason for this. Can I improving anything in performance from my side.

Comment: Add a code sample. `glBindBuffer` is not a draw command, you cannot be drawing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a term 'batch' in computer graphics. In short words, batch is state+draw; if multiple draws happens but state isn't changing, this draws included into the same batch. However, changing state breaks batch and prepares new one. It is CPU intensive task; you should use as little batches as possible, or you'll hit CPU limit.

6 millions batches per frame isn't quite low number. If your objects are small (several elements - sometimes even several hundreds elements), you could merge them all into one vertex array, and add extra vertex attribute containing colour (if you use fixed pipeline - use `glColorPointer`).

If objects are big and colours overhead is too significant - you could use instancing, but it will require modern enough graphics card (but rendering 6 millions objects would be slow without descent GPU anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for response.

I can write pseudo code

```
for(i=0; i < iSize ; ++i )
{
 glColorfv(componet[i].rgba);
 glDrawElements(GL_QUADS,......);// THis is working fine.
}
```

But what I found(feel) is that if componet[i].rgba is same for all i values then the model rotation(handling/zooming etc) are faster compared to the case where all components are with differen colour.

Probably I might have posted like this. Sorry for that.

Comment: You could (and should) edit your question to add information, not place an answer that is not actually answering question.